# Attention in Tensorflow (tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper)

Tags: tensorflow, attention-model

How exactly is `tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper` used? Can someone give a piece of example code? 
Specifically, I only managed to make the following

```
    fwd_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size),10,50,state_is_tuple=True)
    bwd_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size),10,50,state_is_tuple=True)
```

but in Bahdanau et al. 2015, the attention operates on the entire bidirectional RNN. I have no idea how to code that in Tensorflow.

Comment: This is a some nice example code. https://gist.github.com/ilblackdragon/c92066d9d38b236a21d5a7b729a10f12

Comment: Could you figure it out? I have the same question. Thanks!